# Deprecation of Google plus

Tags: node.js, google-plus

I got a email from Google saying that the use of all Google+ APIs are being shut off. I currently use googleAPI.google.plus to sign people in using Google. Is this plugin going to add a update to support the new way of authorizing users with Google?

Environment details:
OS: Mac OS X
Node.js version: v 10.8.0
npm version: v6.5.0
googleapis version: 33

```
const googleAPI = require('googleapis');

const plus = googleAPI.google.plus({
            version: 'v1',
            auth: configs.googleAPIKey // specify your API key here
        });
```

```
 // Check if Google tokens are valid
        plus.people.get({
            userId: googleUserId,
            fields: 'displayName,emails,name,image',
            access_token: googleAccessToken
        })
            .then((user) => {
                logger.debug('From google: ' + util.inspect(user.data));
                logger.debug('First Name: ' + user.data.name.givenName);
                logger.debug('Last Name: ' + user.data.name.familyName);
            })
```

Comment: How would we know? Maybe take a look at https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues?

Comment: Google employees may monitor stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show how you're using that object to do sign-in, so it is a little difficult to answer.

However, the [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package already supports sign-ins with an [OAuth2 client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#oauth2-client) that you can create with something like

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);
```

You can then get a URL to redirect them to so they can sign-in with something like

```
const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  // If you only need one scope you can pass it as a string
  scope: scopes
});
```

and then redirect them to `url`. Once they have signed into that URL, they'll be redirected to the URL you have specified as `YOUR_REDIRECT_URL` which will include a parameter called `code`. You'll need this code to exchange it for credentials, including the auth token

```
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

If you just need to use an [API Key](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#using-api-keys) (which is what your example hints at), then you should just need to include the key the same way you do now for the API calls that you need to make. But that isn't related to authorization.

Since it looks like you want to get profile information, you can use something like userinfo or the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) and choose which fields you want for the user.

Using userinfo might look something like

```
oauth2client.userinfo.get().then( profile => {
  // Handle profile info here
});
```

The people.get method gives you a little more control, and might look something like

```
const people = google.people({
  version: "v1"
});
const fields = [
  "names",
  "emailAddresses",
  "photos"
];
people.people.get({
  resourceName: "people/me",
  personFields: fields.join(',')
})
.then( user => {
  // Handle the user results here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Your right sorry should of added how i do sign in.  Just updated the question to include that.  So i use plus.people.get once i get their token to see if its valid and to get information from google about that user.  This api is apparently being shut down by google.  To continue to be able to do this how would i need to change it?